# Count unique ID from JSON file with wrong hierarchy

Tags: python, json, parsing

I've been given a task to parse data from JSON file.

1. number of unique users in one day
2. number of unique requests (unique = multiple requests of the same item count as one)
3. average time between item_id requests (in the sample data above, the average time between the requests would be 1 minute - computed from the item_id 494398, since the item_id 3147684 was requested only once, so the average would only be computed from )
4. median time between item_id requests (-||-),
5. maximum number of requests per a single item_id for which the variant similarInJsonList was returned.

The hierarchy in JSON file is wrong, there is no exact naming for given user, it's just user id that contains the rest of the info. I couldn't wrap my head around on how to do it, I don't know how to access the information within Python script because each of the user id is unique.

JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "271736829405315319062165375185738528887": {      # user_id
    "494398": [                                     # item_id
      [
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:00:00.546000+00:00",       # datetime of request
          "NotReadyYet"                             # variant returned
        ],
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:01:00.546000+00:00",       # datetime of next visit
          "similarInJsonList"                       # variant returned
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
    "variant": [                                    # not important
      "NotCount",
      ""
    ]
  },
  "327369077869547705509707240484932336059": {      # user_id
    "3147684": [                                    # item_id
      [
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:00:00.437000+00:00",       # datetime of request
          "similarInJsonList"                       # variant returned
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
    "variant": [                                    # not important
      "similarInJsonList",
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a set from the keys you then just need to get the size of the set. That will tell you how many unique user_id existed in your data structure.

```
J = [{
  "271736829405315319062165375185738528887": {      # user_id
    "494398": [                                     # item_id
      [
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:00:00.546000+00:00",       # datetime of request
          "NotReadyYet"                             # variant returned
        ],
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:01:00.546000+00:00",       # datetime of next visit
          "similarInJsonList"                       # variant returned
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
    "variant": [                                    # not important
      "NotCount",
      ""
    ]
  },
  "327369077869547705509707240484932336059": {      # user_id
    "3147684": [                                    # item_id
      [
        [
          "2021-12-02T00:00:00.437000+00:00",       # datetime of request
          "similarInJsonList"                       # variant returned
        ]
      ],
      []
    ],
    "variant": [                                    # not important
      "similarInJsonList",
      ""
    ]
  }
}]

print(len(set(J[0].keys())))
```

**Output:**

```
2
```